# How to handle two different time frames in a single column?

Tags: mysql

I have a data set that shows the ratings for some animated tv series.
"Year" column shows the start year and end year of each show. For some, there are two start and end year values like "1995-1998, 2012-2014". So, for these ones, the show ended and started again.

[the mini table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0j8o.png)

I was trying to create two columns from "Year" column: start_year and end_year.

However, I am not sure how to handle the shows that have two year values (e.g. "1995-1998, 2012-2014"). Should I create a new row for each time frame? In my opinion, this would not change anything as the ratings will be the same (I will do analysis based on the ratings).

For example, to find only the start_date I used the query below:

SELECT SUBSTRING(`Year`, 1, 4) FROM animated_tv_series;

To find the end dates,

SELECT SUBSTRING(`Year`, FROM 6) FROM animated_tv_series;

But then, I have a problem with end_date because of two-year-values. Because, I got a row value as
1998, 2012-2014
which is wrong.

Any suggestions are welcome! Thank you.

First time, I got a problem like this so I don't know how to approach.

Comment: totally depends how you plan to use the start year and end year, and what a gap in the show years means to you.  do you really not have ratings by year?

Comment: seems like the most flexible thing is adding a series_id, and a separate table with series_id and year columns (with one row per year of the series)

Comment: I'd recommend you to normalize your data (see the comment provided by @ysth). As a palliative you may serialize your data to JSON array of objects, for example, `'1995-1998, 2012-2014'` -> `'[{"start":1995, "finish":1998}, {"start":2012, "finish":2014}]'`.

Comment: Thank you all for responses!